# persist embeds_one relation mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

```
class Order
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

 #relationships
  embeds_one :user_detail

  #fields
  field :description

  #validations  
  validates :user_detail, presence: true
end
```

This the embedded object in order:

```
class UserDetail
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #fields
  field :name, :type => String
  field :zip_code, :type => String
  field :email, :type => String

  # Relationships
  embedded_in :order

  #validations
  validates_presence_of :name, :zip_code, :email
end
```

I want save/persist on mongodb `order` object with `user_detail` object `embedded_in` `order` object.

I have tried with:

```
order = Order.new(description: "checking description")
order.user_detail = Order.new(:name => "John", :zip_code => "26545", :email => "john@john.com")
order.save!
```

but I get validation fail:

```
o.save!
Mongoid::Errors::Validations: 
Problem:
  Validation of Order failed.
Summary:
  The following errors were found: User detail is invalid
Resolution:
  Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations....
```

**How can I fix this problem?** I'm using mongoid **3.x**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
order = Order.new(description: "checking description")
order.user_detail = UserDetail.new(:name => "John", :zip_code => "26545", :email => "john@john.com")
order.save!
```

You had `Order.new` for `OrderDetail.new`

Comment: Uppss, thank you it was error. I have edited your response is `UserDetail` instead `OrderDetail`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually create user_detail using

`order.user_detail = UserDetail.new...
 order.save!`

The embedded user_detail will be created automatically if u add autobuild attribute

`embeds_one :user_detail autobuild: true`

If u wanna persist user_detail in database as well, do not forget to add

`validates_presence_of :user_detail`

or you will not see the persisted user_detail in mongo db.